# What is the right way of deploying a typescript application in production?

Tags: node.js, typescript, deployment, production

I have a typescript and nodejs backend application which exposes some REST APIs. I want to deploy this application in production. I have all my typescript files inside a `src/` directory which are compiled to js files inside `dist/` directory. I have also installed all my typescript dependencies as dev dependencies.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.15",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.17.5",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  }
```

Now I can think of two options of running the above application in production.

- Commiting the `dist/` folder and then running the application using `node dist/app.js`. This method is generally not recommended as build artifacts can easily be reproduced.
- Using `npm install` instead of `npm install --omit=dev` which will allow me to build the application using `tsc` and then run it. If I go about this way then having typescript and all the types as dev dependencies don't even make sense.

What is the right way of deploying my typescript application in production and is there a better setup for deploying it?

Comment: Do you containerize it?

Comment: Not right now, but I will eventually.

Comment: "What is the right way" - There is none. There are different solutions for different use cases and without knowing what your app is doing and how you are going to deploy it, makes it hard to answer the question. Can you extend your questions with: What kind of application it is (node, browser, etc.), how you are going to deploy it and how you are going to run it.

Comment: @BrunoMarotta It is a typescript and nodejs application that provides some REST apis. I want to deploy it on a digital ocean droplet.

Comment: Are you going to simply copy the files? Probably the best way is to use some builder/packer like webpack, rollup or eslint. Because it packs all necessary node_modules for you